# I am using facade but didn't get response in var_dump

Tags: laravel, lumen

**facade**

```
$privacy=ProfilePrivacy::get_by_contact($id);
                    $access=json_decode($privacy['access_level'],'true');
                    var_dump($privacy);
```

**helper**

```
public function get_by_contact($id)
    {
        $result=$this->_model->get_by_contact($id);
    }
```

**model**

```
  public function get_by_contact($id)
    {
        $sql=" SELECT privacy_access.user_id,privacy_access.access_level,privacy_access.status,privacy_access.created_at
            FROM privacy_access
            JOIN contacts ON privacy_access.user_id= contacts.id WHERE privacy_access.user_id=?";
        $privacy = DB::select($sql, [$id]);
        return $privacy;

    }
```

i am using var dump to get responce of $privacy but geting null value

Comment: Did you write the aliases in config/app.php ?

Comment: $app->register(App\Providers\ProfilePrivacyServiceProvider::class);